# Django Case When Select

Tags: django, postgresql

I use raw SQL as subquery to achieve the result. But if I make filtering by annotated field, it throws an error connected to wrong (or not stated) alias like this:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "catalog_good"
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the table alias "v0".
```

I want to know if there is an opportunity to make CASE-WHEN-SELECT by Django.
This is a part of code I would like to improve by Django classes:

```
CASE
    WHEN (
        SELECT (score - "catalog_tag"."weight") ^ 2
        FROM "catalog_tag"
        WHERE "catalog_tag"."word" = 'chair' AND "catalog_tag"."good_id" = "catalog_good"."id"
    ) IS NOT NULL THEN (
        SELECT (score - "catalog_tag"."weight") ^ 2
        FROM "catalog_tag"
        WHERE "catalog_tag"."word" = 'chair' AND "catalog_tag"."good_id" = "catalog_good"."id"
    )
    ELSE (score ^ 2)
END
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case

Comment: How can I write subquery SELECT as lookup?